# ASP.net parallel processing web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am creating a web app which will be hitting some web api's to get information. But currently we have a desktop application using multi threading.

Within asp.net web applications how can we leverage the use of multi threading ie. hitting a number of requests to the web api at the same time?

Does each httprequest spin a new instance so we can have a number of concurrent requests happening at the same time?

Any advice would be good

Thanks

Comment: Here are two good articles on [ASP.NET Mutithreading link1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38501/Multi-Threading-in-ASP-NET) / [ASP.NET Mutithreading link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647332.aspx). One more thing Why are you not want to consume the web API from client side?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you use async IO

1. TaskFactory.FromAsync .net 4+
2. async await .net 4.5+
3. Power Threading AsyncEnumerator .net 2+